# Is there a verb or word for this

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb or word for when someone says you should do something, but then ridicules you when you do it or say you are going to. I don't know if this is ineffable, also please don't say contradict.

Comment: It would be good if you could edit your title to at least partially reference the question.  Also,  I'd put that "please don't say contradict" as "I'm looking for something more than 'contradict'" ...

Comment: as for an answer ...  "set you up" as in "set you up for a fall" would very convey a lot of what you're after although it isn't necessarily for ridicule...but more broadly for failure.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for **a fool's errand**:

> [A pointless undertaking.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/fools-errand.html)

Similarly, **a wild goose chase**:

> [any senseless pursuit of an object or end; a hopeless enterprise](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wild-goose-chase)

Or **bait**:

> [to attract, tempt, or captivate; to worry, torment, or persecute, especially with malicious remarks](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bait?s=t)